# Maximum Likelihood for Gaussian distribution

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

I have encountered this question while studying and i am not even sure where to start..
Suppose that $X_1, \cdots , X_n \enspace IID \enspace X \sim N(\mu_o,\sigma^2_o)$
with $\theta_0 = (\mu_0, \sigma^2_0)\in \mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty)$. For n=1 and 2, how would you start to obtain the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat{\theta}_n = \hat{\theta}_n(x)$?

Comment: ...and for extra marks, describe possible shortcomings of any statistical procedure that attempts to estimate a two-membered vector parameter from a single data point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I would try to solve the problem for $n=1$, since this might be simpler.

Proceeding as follows:

- Start by recalling the definition of the MLE, that is:

> The value $\theta_0$ has to take such that the likelihood function maximal.

- Recall the definition of the likelihood function and write down the likelihood function for this case.
- Write the MLE in terms of the likelihood function in an equation and try to solve it.